# How to setup/mock CNAME record locally for a dev environment

Tags: dns, cname

I need to setup a CNAME record locally. The use case is that I have a domain which is being hit in production and I want to change the production DNS settings but I want to verify my setup works by testing the setting locally before I change it in production.

Currently my domain is setup like this:
`A mydomain.com some.ip.addre.ss`

I want to change it to
`CNAME mydomain.com somecnameaddress.com`

I am able to test A record changes by modifying my hosts file but I cannot do this to test CNAME records. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can't create a CNAME for the root domain, it has to be for a subdomain. So you can just create a live CNAME record for some subdomain, check if everything is okay and then change the hostname to the www subdomain (if it also needs to point to `somecnameaddress.com`. As for the root domain, probably it will be best to create a web redirection/forwarding from `mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com`, after you make the CNAME for `www.mydomain.com` and it propagates.

Answer (score -19, accepted):

For IP address mapping -
You can do this by adding a entry in your local `/etc/hosts` file instead of updating the CNAME. Just add Your live domain and IP address of you test environment, it should work.

For CNAME mapping -
You need to use a dns server opensource or hosted is your choice.

Comment: A CNAME record maps aliases one domain name to another domain name. A hosts file maps a domain name to an IP address. This answer does not answer the specific question and is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

/etc/host cannot point cname

i use dns server (open source)

Technitium https://technitium.com/dns/
u create zone and point to cname

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing APIs etc the Telerik Fiddler application has a HOSTS function which accommodates local CNAME changes as well as A records to override the windows hosts file.

[Override Windows HOSTS file](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledge-base/hosts)